# RegEx visualizer tool

Tags: javascript, php, regex, windows-7

1 - Is there any software that can get a regex string and **render a diagram or some similar stuff**  that can be used to analyze it. I tried some Windows and web apps, but unfortunately **no one provided visualization.**

2 - In [this](http://webtechtuts.com/2011/06/06/regex-how-a-regex-engine-works-internally/) page there was a screen-shot of such an app, but nothing else. Does anybody know its name?

[image]

Comment: I think that's [Regex Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/).

Comment: http://www.regextester.com/ is free, but only says "matches" or "No match." antlr will give you the Rails diagram and has a similar tester.

Comment: @Reza, I posted an answer with a link and a screen shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image you have is from [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/). It is [free to use, but they do encourage to give a fee to support it](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/#license).

See full screenshot:

[image: The Regex Coach]
<sub>(source: [webmasterpoint.org](http://www.webmasterpoint.org/img/guide/53/coach_regex.JPG))</sub>

I've used the tool a lot previously and can recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, That is a very useful app, in particular its tree and step tabs.

Answer (score 5):

I recently found this http://www.regexper.com/. You can visualize the Javascript-style regex. Very handy. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's useful, but it seems not work on some regex, like: `<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>`.

Comment: @PHPst I just tried, it worked for me. Are you saying the rendered graph is not correct or the graph does not show up?

Comment: @PHPst What does this regex do? I think you need to escape the square brackets if you want treat it as a regular char.

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/ this one is also good

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't tell you the name of that particular tool but this is a tool I use a lot:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ - you can input strings that you want to match/replace on, and when you hover over the individual rules in your expression you can get more information on what they are doing. Doesn't provide a diagram, though.

It's web based, rather than downloadable software

Answer (score 3):

[antlr](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Five+minute+introduction+to+ANTLR+3) may be more than you're looking for; it's a lexer and a parser that will generate Java, C, C#, or Ruby. There is a wonderful Eclipse plug-in. You can use just the lexer if you want to parse regex. Here's a screen shot of the tutorial Expr grammar from Eclipse Indigo SR2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Dynamic Regex Highlighting

I've written an open source JavaScript tool which provides dynamic highlighting of regexes published on a web page. The [test page for this project](http://jmrware.github.com/DynamicRegexHighlighter/DynamicRegexHighlighterTester.html) allows you to enter a regex then dynamically highlight the various matching delimiters by mousing over them. It gives a pop-up message giving the capture group number for capturing groups. I find it to be pretty handy.

See: [Dynamic Regex Highlighting with Javascript!](http://jmrware.github.com/DynamicRegexHighlighter/)